# How can i remove the gap between this plane and my liquid mesh?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have attached an image of my scene. On the plane, liquid effector is selected. I check "is planar" sampling substeps 50. Thickness is 0.00. DOMAIN SETTINGS: resolution division: 128. timecale: 0.5. CFL number: 4.0. Particles max 32 particles min 16. Fractional obstacles checked. obstacle distance 0.01 Threshold 0.050. upres factor 2. particle radius 2.0.
Any and all help is appreciated! [image]

Comment: i am pretty sure it is your resolution. Just increase it and you should see that the gap is getting thinner. But tbh ....why don't you just make the collider invisible and double it (remove collision) and move it close to fake that there is no gap? Because increasing the resolution will take hours more to bake and render, and just doubling the object and adapting the size you can do in minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: I would recommend the same (Chris - hidden obstacle from rendering ...or bake fluid and move obstacle after that). Fractional Obstacle is trying only to smooth cubish steepness. For better contact there is $ Flip Fluid add, that has feature for that, that worked for me [see this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/flip-fluids-addon-a-liquid-fluid-simulation-tool-for-blender/702503?page=33) ... or if you want to stay with build in features and your obstacle is complex you can try Booleans, but it is calculation heavy.

Comment: Booleans? Can you explain more about how booleans would be used in this situation or with fluid in general? Also thank you for the help.